Fuzzy Match 2 Large Pandas Dataframes
I have 2 pandas dataframes that both contain company names. I want to left join df1(~10k rows) with df2(~1.6m rows) on company names using a fuzzy match. My current function takes too long to run, so I would like to know if there's any efficient way to do so?
I have tried fuzzy_merge, rapidfuzz + process.extractOne(). Is there a way to modify my current function? Or even better, another package to use(but not fuzzy-matcher because my laptop just couldn't allow it for no reason...)
Some sample data from df1 and df2.
df1 (10k rows)



df1_ID
Company Name




AB0091
Apple


AC0092
Microsoft



df2 (1.6m rows)



df2_ID
Entity Name




F001ABC
Appl


F001AKC
Appl Inc


F001AJQ
Apple Farm


E002ABG
The microst


E002ACG
Minecraft


E004ABG
Microsoft Inc



Ideal output (After fuzzy match and select the highest matched record)



df1_ID
Company Name
df2_ID
Entity Name
Matching Score




AB0091
Apple
F001ABC
Appl
91


AC0092
Microsoft
E004ABG
Microsoft Inc
100



The following codes are the function I'm using right now
def fuzzy_match(row, df2, key, threshold=70):
    best_match = process.extractOne(row['Company Name'], df2['Entity Name'], score_cutoff=threshold)
    if best_match:
        matched_id = df2.loc[df2['Entity Name'] == best_match[0], 'df2_ID'].values[0]
        return pd.Series([best_match[0], matched_id, best_match[1]])
    return pd.Series([None, None, None])

new_df[['Matched_Company', 'df2_ID', 'Name_Matching_Score']] = df1.apply(fuzzy_match, axis=1, df2=df2, key='Company Name')

I have asked the question before, and that's how I got the above function. But really appreciate if there's any more efficient method to solve my problem. Thank you.
How to do fuzzy merge with 2 large pandas dataframes?

@user19077881 No. I just checked it on pandas website but can't really figure out how I can use it in my case here. Would you mind share some similar examples? Thanks!
